# Invalid object name using native query with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to use @Query to do nativeQuery using JPA, so I wrote this:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT TOP (?1) stg.*, a.alias " +
            "FROM EVENTS_TABLE e WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST) " +
            "INNER JOIN areas a ON e.zone_code = a.zone_id " +
            "WHERE e.company_id = ?2 AND e.processed = ?3 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Event> getEventsToProcess(Integer bachSize,
                                      String companyCode,
                                      Boolean processed);
```

Here, I have a query to get some records, that I have to lock, so others pods don't get the same data.

But for that I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'EVENTS_TABLE'.

That's a strange error  because I do have this table in my database, and this works if I put the whole database path, like: "database.schema.EVENTS_TABLE".

But by database name and schema configurations already on application.proprierties. its like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myapplication-name
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://server;database=databasename;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    username: username
    password: password
    continue-on-error: true
    initialization-mode: always
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 30000 #default 30000
      idleTimeout: 60000 #default 600000
      maxLifetime: 100000 #default 1800000
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
        order_updates: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        format_sql: false
        current_session_context_class: thread
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
        default_schema: myschema
```

The question is: Am I missing something?
Why I have to put the whole database path to this works on native query?

I'm using nativeQuery because hibernate refuses to do the lock only on Events and not in the area table, so I can't change the JQPL or something like that for now!

Also, I tried the same code on other free SQL Server from Azure, and it works fine! So what could this be? Some database configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The schema is set based on the user who is logging in, and is by default `dbo`. You should be able to do `SomeSchema.EVENTS_TABLE` (without the database name) and ideally you should always write this way, see also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290155/220697 and https://sqlenlight.com/support/help/sa0157/

Comment: Also consider... your other table name is lowercase, `areas`. If your database is using a case sensitive collation then `EVENTS_TABLE` is not the same thing as `events_table`.